# How to I increase brightness in Unity using scroll or swipe?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having an application in which I have to increase android brightness using the swipe up and down but the issue is I want to increase the brightness continuously If I scroll up and decrease also if I scroll down. My code is

```
if(t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
         {
              //save ended touch 2d point
             secondPressPos = new Vector2(t.position.x,t.position.y);
                           
              //create vector from the two points
             currentSwipe = new Vector3(secondPressPos.x - firstPressPos.x, secondPressPos.y - firstPressPos.y);
               
             //normalize the 2d vector
             currentSwipe.Normalize();
 
             //swipe upwards
             if(currentSwipe.y > 0 && currentSwipe.x > -0.5f && currentSwipe.x < 0.5f)
             {
        if(Brightness >= 1.0f)
        {
            Brightness = 1.0f;
        }
        else if (Brightness <= -1.0f){
        Brightness = 0.0f;
        }

        else{
        Brightness = Brightness + 0.2f;
        }
             }
}
```

This code works only If I want to increase or decrease the brightness by some value but then I have to swipe again which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply not normalize the vector but rather use it as a factor like e.g.

```c#
// Configure some threshold (in pixels) the user has to swipe before changing the brightness
[SerializeField] private float THRESHOLD = 0f;

// Since the position change is in pixels of the display
// configure here how this movement is mapped into your brightness change
[SerializeField] private float SENSITIVITY = 0.01f;

private void Update()
{
    if(Input.touchCount < 1) return;

    var t = Input.GetTouch(0);

    switch (t.phase)
    {
        case TouchPhase.Began:
            firstPressPos = t.position;
            break;

        case TouchPhase.Moved:
            secondPressPos = t.position;

            var currentSwipe = secondPressPos - firstPressPos;

            if(Mathf.Abs(currentSwipe.x) < 0.5f && Mathf.Abs(currentSwipe.y) > THRESHOLD)
            {
                // remove the threshold amount
                currentSwipe.y -= Mathf.Sign(currentSwipe.y) * THRESHOLD;

                // Smooth change the brightness instead of stepwise
                // depending on how far the user swiped
                Brightness += currentSwipe.y * SENSITIVITY;

                // Sanatize value between 0 and 1
                Brightness = Mathf.Clamp(Brightness, 0, 1);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```